# PHP Two Exclaimation Mark "!!" Operator with preg_match?

Tags: php, operators

Saw this online in one PHP snippet [here](http://pastebin.com/KKaQ21gk).

```
/**
 * @param string $str subject of test for integerness
 * @return bool true if argument is an integer string
 */
function intStr($str) {
    return !!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $str);
}
```

Running this code snippet produces:

```
> var_dump( intStr("abc") );
bool(false)

> var_dump( intStr("123") );
bool(true)
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the dual exclamation mark a a valid operator, or is it just the same as a "not-not", which negates itself?
2. **Also**, why is this operator used in-conjunction with the `preg_match` function?

Comment: The comments say it all: _@return bool true [...]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preg_match returns 0 or 1 (or false on error) and this intStr function is meant to return a boolean value. A single `!$x` first converts `$x` to boolean, then negates. `!!$x` just reverts this negation, so it is a shorter way to write `(bool)$x`.

However, this saving of four characters results in loss of readability (and two unneccessary operations, but that's negligible), so it's not recommended.

It's clever code, but there is a rule in programming: **[Don't be clever](http://www.codethinked.com/dont-be-clever)**

Answer (score 0):

**Running this simplified function:**

```
function test($value) {
    return !!$value;
}
```

**Tests:**

```
> var_dump( test(1) );
bool(true)

> var_dump( test(0) );
bool(false)

> var_dump( test('1') );
bool(true)

> var_dump( test('0') );
bool(false)

> var_dump( is_bool( test('abc') ) );
bool(true)

> var_dump( is_bool( test('0') ) );
bool(true)
```

**Observations:**

Checked output using `is_bool`. *Apparently it somehow casts/forces the output to a **boolean**.*

**Conclusion:**

From the PHP manual,

> `preg_match()` returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

I can conclude that this function forces the return value to be a boolean value, instead of the possibility of an integer value returned by `preg_match`.

Comment: to a boolean actually

Answer (score 0):

`!!` is equal to `not not`. That means that `!!'a'` will cast the string `'a'` to a boolean, and return the inverse of that. So, `!!preg_match` means `not not preg_match`, so a valid preg_match.